# need to make a restful web service call

Tags: rest, resteasy

I have built restful web services using resteasy, now i want to call these web services... i did a bit of research and came across diff names Jersey, Restlet,Resteasy client framework and a few others.. now i am confused as to which one of these to use.. does any one of these have a big advantage over others..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can implement hello world applications to see which one easier for you.

I tried Resteasy and jersey. Coding style is 90% same for those 2.

However, my very simple application for resteasy and jersey, returning a simple response for the same URI, resulted: resteasy is almost 20 times faster than jersey when the number of concurrent users goes up.

Although, this does not mean it is gonna be like that all the time, it may give you an idea. I used default settings, maybe some other settings needs to be changed for better performance in jersey.

jersey was able to handle maxium of 500 concurrent users, 10 requests each whereas resteasy was able to perform up to 2000 concurrent users, 10 per request. 
At 500 concurrent users, resteasy was performing 18 times faster than jersey.

You may want to try something simple that demonstrates your needs with all the candidate frameworks to see how they perform. And in the meantime by doing this, you will also get an idea about how things work in each of them.